# Supervisor who accepted me for a research internship now says he doesn't know who I am

Tags: research-undergraduate, email, supervision, internship

I've been accepted in a research internship. However, after I sent an email to my supervisor asking about some details, he told me that he has no idea about who I am, and that maybe I've been exchanging with someone else. But the confirmation letter was signed by him.

I'm so confused, I'm afraid if I send more emails it would look like I'm forcing things. I'm really confused because I refused many offers to work in this lab. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is it possible that there are two individuals with the same name?

Comment: No it’s not possible, I already discussed with the professor, I think he just forgot ... which is a bit weird

Comment: When you say "I've already discussed with the professor" what exactly does that mean? Did you email, meet on Zoom, speak on the phone?

Comment: No just by email, he put me in contact with another professor with whom I had the interview

Comment: Are you sure that the professor who signed the letter is to be your supervisor, and did not simply sign it in some administrative capacity? Particularly since you say some other professor interviewed you for the position. If it is a structured internship program, the professor who signed could be the program coordinator, for instance.

Comment: @GoodDeeds he’s my supervisor and it’s even mentioned in the letter of acceptance

Comment: @pjc50 That's exactly what the very first comment asks about here. :)

Comment: Did you pay anything for this "internship"? It could be a possible scam.

Comment: I know of a professor who one day came and said he had a new PhD student he didn't know about, because he forgot to have accepted him. But bottom line, he had a new student, he signed and accepted him, so that already done. Likely the professor will work with you, but if you got acceptance and he forgot, its his problem, not yours :)

Comment: Professors are people, too. Probably just slipped his mind. Nothing wrong with reminding him, telling him you have the letter of acceptance. It pains me to admit it, but I could see myself doing something like this, so it's not so surprising.

Comment: This is a great story. An update would be nice ;)

Comment: @AyoubAjarra Where was the interview with the "other professor" conducted?  In person?  Remotely?  Did you actually set foot in the institution you think you're going to attend?  Do you know for certain that the person who interviewed you is actually a professor at that university?  **Did you pay anyone any money?**

Comment: Sorry guys for the late response, I am going through some hard times lately because of what happened, I’m shocked and disappointed, this is my last year internship that I take too seriously, unfortunately this is not ethical coming from one of the best labs in the world, I don’t know what to do now ...

Comment: I didn’t pay anything ... but from what I’ve heard, they recruited another intern for the same position, the other intern is paid and they’re preparing his visa and work authorization, unlike me... I’ve been ghosted for a long time ... I was hoping this is just a joke, I rejected many paid good offers to start this internship that isn’t even paid ... Anyway, I don’t know anymore what words would best express my situation ... I’m just disappointed and lost hope.

Comment: @AyoubAjarra It's been two days - did you not follow up with the professor since then, like the top answer suggests?  Don't wait - do that now!

Comment: @J... I did, I’m trying not to give details about the lab or the professor ... I tried the best I can, the professor gives me short answers or doesn’t answer me at all.

Comment: The RH sent me the internship agreement with a stipend salary, then later, told me it was a mistake and that the internship is non funded.... These are certainly the worst conditions that an intern can work on, now I just regret all the good offers that I withdrew because I’ve been dreaming to work with this brilliant professor... he’s one of the best researchers in the world and I am very grateful for the opportunity he gave me ... but after all, it seems like it wasn’t what I really imagined ...

Comment: You need to get one of your local faculty involved to help you on this ASAP. Whoever the faculty member you have the best relationship is, show them the information and ask if they will email the other faculty to try to work out a fair solution given the situation.

Comment: So in the meantime, what has happened?

Answer (score 69):

I would send him the signed documents in e-mail, asking him if it was signed by him. His answer would shed light on things (he forgot he signed, he didn't read before signing, etc.) 
But don't think that you're pushing things. An internship is important, and you already got a signed document and you need to know things to plan forward...

Comment: Rather than sending the signed document, consider emailing, "I have this paper letter confirming my internship and notifying me that I'll be working with you.  I'd like to make the necessary plans."  That way, you don't shove it down the supervisor's throat, so to speak, but you can still send it if the supervisor asks for it or continues to maintain that there's been a mistake.

Comment: NO, don't send signed documents (other than copies). You need to retain them.

Comment: @Buffy Sorry I wasn't clear.  I. and probably others, had in mind scanned copies f the paper documents.  Yes, hang onto that original!

Comment: @BobBrown I was figuring it was even digitally signed ...

Comment: But I can't say that phrasing is that much politer than saying "wait didn't you sign this?" If you send it, he can say "Oh, yeah all hiring decisions need to be signed by a full prof so I signed for my assoc prof buddy" (or whatever arcane rule)

Comment: First make sure you are talking to the right person. I've personally been in a situation before where 2 people with the same name are working for the same organisation. I would only send a signed document if you are sure that you are talking to the right person.

Comment: I live 1/2 mile from someone with almost the exact same name as me (same pronunciation in Hebrew, different English first name). We are not related. But enough volunteer organizations in common that confusion happens a **lot**, especially by email. I have fun with: "The tall one?" "With the beard?" "Who does computer stuff?" "Who reads the Torah?" (knowing full well based on the question being asked that someone is looking for the *other* guy - and I know he gets calls/emails for me, too.)

Comment: @BobBrown why not shove it down their throat , so to speak? I mean, the answer oj got throwing them into doud and uncertainty isn't exactly polite. I'd tell them outright that I had an interview with x and send thrm a copy of them letter and ask if I have fallen victim to a scam. Not impolitely, but directly.

Comment: @user1841243 Why stop at two? Following some medical treatment at hospital, I'm being monitored for various conditions by three specialist nurses, in different departments, called Diane Smith, Diane Smith, and Dianne Smith. Endless fun and confusion!

Comment: @DonQuiKong Because one does not gratuitously annoy the person who, if all goes well, will be one's immediate superior.

Comment: @Buffy I assumed we are talking about e-mails, not letters. That's why I didn't specify that the op shouldn't post original documents..

Comment: I just thought a clarification was essential. The OPs assumption and yours might be different. Perhaps you should edit and make my comment moot.

Comment: Please also suggest that OP do this while apologizing and politely asking for the correspondent's help in clearing up the confusion - as opposed to an angry-sounding: "Is this your signature?" email.

Comment: @DonQuiKong That is a great way to start off on the wrong foot with your supervisor and immediately get labeled "difficult". People make mistakes, that happens. The correct way is to politely inquire and clarify, not to go nuclear about what might very well just be a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 34):

Don't read too much in to this. There are a variety of possible explanations, including a miscommunication between the PI and the person with whom you had the interview. It is also possible that the PI is very busy and a bit distracted and someone who delegates a lot of such things to others, such as the person you interviewed with.

I would suggest just reminding both of the state of affairs as you see them and ask again (both people) for the details you need. Hopefully everyone will get "on the same page" soon.

Comment: this seems like just a guess that has no basis on the question asked and really should be a comment.

Comment: @blankip: what kind of answer would you expect to "my future supervisor does not recognize me"? Something like "there is a rule 23-49 in the official Yale handbook that states a supervisor will forget students in 42% of cases"? All the answers will obviously go from "he is busy, to ""he delegated and someone fucked up", to "he may have a brain damage". Anything will be speculation for such a question.

Answer (score 13):

Send him an email with a copy of the acceptance letter. Don't phrase the email as "you were wrong", but rather express that you are confused, that maybe there is a misunderstanding.

If the prof is a reasonable person things will improve from there. Otherwise, you could contact the admissions office that sent you the letter, explaning the situation. That said, if you get to this second stage, it is not clear if it is to your advantage to work with this person.

Comment: Why should one express being confused when one is not confused?

Comment: Out of politeness and pragmatism. There is little to gain from telling idiots that they are idiots. If you tell someone "you are wrong", in particular when the person is supposed to be some kind of authoritative figure, it goes bad more often than not. It shouldn't, but it does.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that one should not say that someone is wrong. One should just state facts, like: "I have this signed paper from you, which should confirm that I am not exchanging". The shorter the better, to my opinion.

Comment: @yarchik: I wouldn't say "I have this signed paper from *you*", because it comes across as accusing, and at this stage you're *not* 100% certain that you have the right person (as others have mentioned, it's not that uncommon for there to be two people with the same name, or at least similar enough names that their email addresses are easily confused). If it's the wrong person and you're polite, they're much more likely to send a helpful response ("Ah, you need Dr Xyz, whose email address is x.xyz@example.edu, I'm Dr Xyzz xyzz@example.edu. People always get us mixed up").

Comment: +1 for stressing a non-confrontational, non-accusing tone.

Comment: @yarchik: 1. OP literally says they're confused.... 2. You could phrase it as "Perhaps I have gotten confused, but" or "I hope I am not confusing you with someone else, but the acceptance letter seems to indicate that XYZ". etc.

Answer (score 2):

You do not indicate whether you have exchanged emails or calls in person with this supervisor. (At the very least, my email program will remember who I've interacted with even if I don't, and I confess that this has at times been my first checkpoint.) However, I suspect that your dealings thus far have been with a different person and that you and the supervisor have simply been assigned to one another. However, s/he did sign the letter. It is quite possible that they may not remember this as their PA gives them a pile of letters to sign everyday (but then it would be unprofessional for them to plead complete ignorance, if they have a PA with whom they can check what happened!). There could also be a bog standard mix-up.

In any case, be forewarned that this mess is a sign of things to come. You will be supervised by an overworked junior staff member or postdoc, your supervisor will rarely if ever see you and most likely still not have the slightest clue who you are when the internship is done, unless you deliver them a high-impact manuscript they can put their name to.